Android - Google Drive Authorization API
Can somebody help with a non-deprecated working code in Java just to authorize and allow the user to interact with Google Drive (upload/download file) ?
Currently I have put together this code:
 requestSignIn();

    private void requestSignIn() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                .build();

        GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);

        Intent signInIntent = client.getSignInIntent();
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
    }

final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    handleSignInInent(result.getData());
                } else {
                    showMsgSnack(getString(R.string.nologin));
                }
            });

    private void handleSignInInent(Intent data) {
        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(googleSignInAccount -> {
                    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.
                            usingOAuth2(BackupActivity.this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

                    credential.setSelectedAccount(googleSignInAccount.getAccount());

                    Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder(
                            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                            new GsonFactory(),
                            credential )
                            .setApplicationName("Hrady")
                            .build();

                    driveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);

                    RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.logscreen);
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.logmenu);
                    relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> showMsgSnack(getString(R.string.nologin)));
    }

This is working fine, however GoogleSignInClient and also GoogleSignIn are deprecated.
i did not find any complete working solution, I tried to google, ChatGPT, Google documentation, nothing helped to replace my existing code.
The closest solution I tried is this:
AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest
        .builder()
        .setRequestedScopes(Collections.singletonList(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)))
        .build();

Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
        .authorize(authorizationRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener(
                authorizationResult -> {
                    if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                        // access needs to be granted by the user
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = authorizationResult.getPendingIntent();
                        try {
                            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 999, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.i("TTTT", "Couldn't start Authorization UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    } else {
                        // access already granted, continue with user action
                        Log.i("TTTT", "access already granted");
                         saveToDriveAppFolder(authorizationResult);
                    }
                })
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.i("TTTT", "Failed to authorize", e));

But here startIntentSenderForResult is deprecated and when the access should be granted and saveToDriveAppFolder(authorizationResult); should be called, not sure how to reflect this in my existing code.
Because in my code in handleSignInInent I am using credential from this:
 GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.
                            usingOAuth2(BackupActivity.this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

                    credential.setSelectedAccount(googleSignInAccount.getAccount());

                    Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder(
                            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                            new GsonFactory(),
                            credential )
                            .setApplicationName("MYAPP")
                            .build();

And I can't use there authorizationResult.

I can't even documentation of what dependency to use to get the authorization classes like Identity and AuthorizationRequest. Would you mind sharing your dependency?


for "startIntentSenderForResult is deprecated", use ActivityResultLauncher:

    val authorizationResult = Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
                    .getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(result.data)
    ...
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = authorizationResult.pendingIntent
    val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent).build()
                        authorizationLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest)


for "saveToDriveAppFolder(authorizationResult)":

val accessToken = authorizationResult.accessToken
        val credential = GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
            .setJsonFactory(GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
            .build()
            .setAccessToken(accessToken)

        return Drive.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            credential
        )
            .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .build()


I might be wrong but new Google Drive Authorization API might be returning null for val signInAccount = authorizationResult?.toGoogleSignInAccount()?.account

Yes, authorizationResult?.toGoogleSignInAccount() is returning null for me as well.

Take a look at this response here.  It's Java instead of Kotlin but it has worked for generating the credential and then authentication the Drive service to use with the API.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/78605090/810674

fix this by:
val accessToken = authorizationResult.accessToken
val credential = GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
.setJsonFactory(GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
.build()
.setAccessToken(accessToken)
    return Drive.Builder(
        GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
        credential
    )


Google now recommends the use of Google Identity Services (GIS) for sign-in and authorization. You need to use AuthorizationRequest for scopes and handle intents with the newer ActivityResultContracts.
I read some docs (here https://developers.google.com/identity and here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java) and I asked ChatGPT to help me to make an example using the new approach, and here is the result. I hope it helps:
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.AuthorizationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.AuthorizationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.Identity;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.PendingIntent;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

import java.util.Collections;

public class DriveAuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "DriveAuthActivity";
    private static final String APP_NAME = "MYAPP";
    private DriveServiceHelper driveServiceHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestAuthorization();
    }

    private void requestAuthorization() {
        AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.builder()
                .setRequestedScopes(Collections.singletonList(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)))
                .build();

        Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
                .authorize(authorizationRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(authorizationResult -> {
                    if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                        try {
                            authorizationLauncher.launch(authorizationResult.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error starting Authorization UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Directly proceed if no resolution is needed
                        handleAuthorizationResult(authorizationResult);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, "Authorization failed", e));
    }

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> authorizationLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
                    AuthorizationResult authorizationResult = Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
                            .getAuthorizationFromIntent(result.getData());
                    if (authorizationResult != null) {
                        handleAuthorizationResult(authorizationResult);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Authorization result is null");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Authorization failed or cancelled");
                }
            });

    private void handleAuthorizationResult(AuthorizationResult authorizationResult) {
        if (authorizationResult.toGoogleSignInAccount() != null) {
            // Use the account to create a Drive service
            GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential
                    .usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
            credential.setSelectedAccount(authorizationResult.toGoogleSignInAccount().getAccount());

            try {
                Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder(
                        GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                        credential)
                        .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                        .build();

                driveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
                Log.i(TAG, "Drive Service created successfully");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error creating Drive Service", e);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign-In Account is null");
        }
    }
}

An here, the helper (DriveServiceHelper.java)
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;

public class DriveServiceHelper {
    private final Drive mDriveService;

    public DriveServiceHelper(Drive driveService) {
        this.mDriveService = driveService;
    }

    // Implement file upload, download, etc.
}


There is now AuthorizationResult.getGoogleSignInAccount() there is AuthorizationResult.toGoogleSignInAccount() but it may be returning null in this new library

@nLL you are right. I edited the answer. Thanks!

Have you tested this? Last time I have tested "toGoogleSignInAccount" always returned null. I've ended up with this https://gist.github.com/NLLAPPS/00f2ad273bc6aa92265a8c1bdd6c2ba6
